# Get Value between 2 dates C# / SQL Statement

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to retrieve Employee_Share, Entity_Share, Government_Share.

When user enters the `Start_Period` and `End_Period` which datatype I want to get back the specific shares between this dates. Also, the problem in some cases I have null value for `End_Period` in my database. I want any help with select query:

Example: my database

```
Start_period    End_Period   Employee_Share   Entity_Share  Government_Share
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
01/01/1994       01/01/1998      0.7              0.14           0.17
12/03/1998       null            0.7               0               0
11/01/2011       09/09/2013      0.8               0              0.9
```

I am trying something like in C#:

```
string ReadShare = "select EMPLOYEE_SHARE, GOVERMENT_SHARE, ENTITY_SHARE, END_PERIOD";
ReadShare = ReadShare + " from cpms.UNPAID_LEAVES_RUALES where";
ReadShare = ReadShare + " TYPE = " + rsnew["LEAVE_TYPE"].ToString();
ReadShare = ReadShare + " and PAY_OPTION = " + rsnew["LEAVE_PAY_OPTION"].ToString();
ReadShare = ReadShare + " and REASON = " + rsnew["LEAVE_REASON"].ToString();
ReadShare = ReadShare + " and START_PERIOD <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(rsnew["FROM_DATE"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'";
ReadShare = ReadShare + " and (END_PERIOD is null OR ('" + Convert.ToDateTime(rsnew["FROM_DATE"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "' <= nvl(END_PERIOD, '01/01/2500')))";
```

Comment: If what you tried doesn't work, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Please let us know what DBMS you are using.  Also, tell us what **rsnew["FROM_DATE"].ToString()** evaluates to.

Comment: am using oracle db and the FROM_DATE" refer to start_period

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the next line after this one. See what is the value of `ReadShare` variable and post that here.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection